# async.eachSeries gives error callback is not defined

Tags: async.js

```
  async.eachSeries([1,2,3], async(item, callback) => {
      //await delay(6000);
      console.log(item);
      callback(null);
    }, function(done) {
      if(done == null){
      }
    });
```

> This happens when we add async with iterator, but we need async to call a await.

Comment: means the callback argument is not a function. You have to define it like callback(value){}

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans  can you please more clarify it